# Creating web applications with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am new to creating Web applications in JAVA and I am kind of confused. After googling for a while, I decided that the best framework to do it with is Spring MVC. I don't want to create anything fancy, just get a little familiar with web application creation. 
I know there is not one correct choice, but would you advice me using Spring MVC? 
If no, what are the best alternatives? 
And do you have any resources that could start me going with Spring MVC? What I have to know about Spring? Blogs, documentations?

Comment: a great alternative is StripesFramework.  A lot easier for a beginner

Comment: Rooman, your question is too broad. We can't reply you in the common StackOverflow format. You question should be debated on a forum, because it really implies personal opinion. The only advise I can give you is to see what AppFuse do with Spring MVC : http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Using+Spring+MVC

Comment: Thank you for the responses! Yes, I know it is too broad, but personal opinion is exactly what I wanted to hear. And alternatives.

Comment: You could have a look at [springfuse.com](http://www.springfuse.com/), a preconfigured webapp generator. There's no Spring MVC template anymore, but JSL via PrimeFaces which could be a good choice too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you are new to Java web applications, you could also look at the http://www.playframework.com/ which is much easier to start with. 
From my own experience you can concentrate on the problem and you don't have to mess with the config.

Answer (score 1):

You can go through a good comparision of Java Web Frameworks here:

[The Curious Coder’s Java Web Frameworks Comparison: Spring MVC, Grails, Vaadin, GWT, Wicket, Play, Struts and JSF](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/the-curious-coders-java-web-frameworks-comparison-spring-mvc-grails-vaadin-gwt-wicket-play-struts-and-jsf/)

I personally prefer Spring MVC.

You can find a wast collection of spring tutorials from:

1. [Spring Official Site](http://spring.io/docs)
2. [JavaBrains](http://javabrains.koushik.org/p/spring-framework.html)
3. [TutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/index.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Well, like every other question in software development, the response starts with **it depends**. It depends on what application you want to build.

As for resources...you can start from [here](http://spring.io/blog/2011/01/04/green-beans-getting-started-with-spring-mvc/) or [here](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-mvc-tutorials/). The one that I preferred when getting started with spring was: [this - step by step](http://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/) (as kindly posted in comments Atul - thank you, Atul) the step-by-step is just for `spring 2.5`. If you like a more hands-on approach and just check code samples, you can check the [spring samples repo](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/).

Comment: I would not start with Spring MVC step by step with Spring version 2.5 or earlier. While it gives you an idea about the internals and how things work, if I am starting fresh I would rather start with Spring 3.x

Comment: I agree, but I didn't find the equivalent resource for 3.x